# Default code in each new cpp files in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am currently studying C++ using Visual Studio and I don't want to use a new project for each and every small topic that I go through, instead, I have one project into which I Add and Remove Cpp files as needed.

I wonder if there is a possibility to set a default piece of code into each newly added Cpp file so that I don´t need to copy it every time. Some simple code like this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{




cin.get()
return 0;
}
```

Comment: the links you provide describe how to set it up for each new Project not for each new File within the same project which is what I asked about

Comment: Set up a source control repository with your template in the master branch. Create a new branch from master for each project. VS has built-in git functionality these days. (This will also help you establish the very good habit of using source control.)

Comment: I believe you can also make "code snippets" in VS, and insert them with a key shortcut.

Comment: Just an alternative if you do not stick to MSVS: eclipse offers configurable code file templates...

Comment: See [Creating Project and Item Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247121.aspx).

Comment: For example projects I use tortoise svn to copy and rename a folder that is in the repository then have CMake glob add all folders and then I regenerate the visual studio project after renaming the project in the folders `CMakeLists.txt`. All of this takes less than 1 minute.